# How to use arrow keys to navigate from input field to ReactJS searchable autocomplete list?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, focus, onkeydown

Using this [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-lovelace-irw9it?file=/src/Autocomplete.jsx), I would like to add in the functionality of arrowing up and down through the dropdown items.

To do this, I think I need to remove the activeSuggestion className from the first item in the list (possibly by using -1 in the index or something), until the user presses the down arrow. When that happens, I would also like remove focus from the input field and bring it to the first item in the list.

Desired functionality:

- User types in "A" to autocomplete, filtering out a few items (focus is in the input field)
- User presses down arrow, which brings focus from input field to "Alligator". Alligator is now the "activeSuggestion" and is highlighted.
- User arrows back up, bringing the focus back to the input field. Alligator is no longer highlighted.

[image]

I tried messing with the index, activesuggestion, and userinput values (+1, 0, -1). This snippet comes from my [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-lovelace-irw9it?file=/src/Autocomplete.jsx)

```
  onKeyDown = (e) => {
    const { activeSuggestion, filteredSuggestions } = this.state;

    // User pressed the enter key
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.setState({
        activeSuggestion: 0,
        userInput: filteredSuggestions[activeSuggestion]
      });
    }
    // User pressed the up arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      if (activeSuggestion === 0) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion - 1 });
    }
    // User pressed the down arrow
    else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      if (activeSuggestion - 1 === filteredSuggestions.length) {
        return;
      }

      this.setState({ activeSuggestion: activeSuggestion + 1 });
    }
  };
```

Thanks for your help - I really appreciate any feedback!